# Java Script error suppress

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Is there any way any error happens on page we can suppress the error. When we he have Iframe where we are loading third party websites which we don't have any control

Comment: try/catch, without a throw in the catch will stop the error showing, you'd need to be able to wrap the code in them though.

Comment: @Rudu: A try/catch works for 3rd party content in an iframe?

Comment: @jbabey Not everyone has that freedom, especially if you're serving ads

Answer (score 0):

Only way to suppress the error is if the code runs on your domain and you can catch it with [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror). If it is on theirs [in iframe/frame], there is nothing you can do.

Tell them to fix it or do not include their page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the code or behavior of a site from a different domain that's in an iframe or a frame.  The browser prevents any cross domain modifications.  See the ["same origin policy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) at MDN for details.

It would take a browser plug-in to do what you are describing.  If you want to display third party sites in an iframe/frame, you get whatever behavior they produce.